# Filter one array according to data in another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays of random numbers, `X` and `Y`. X represents x-coordinates and `Y` represents y-coordinates. I want to filter `X` such that I only keep indices `i` of `X` where:

```
X[i]^2 + Y[i]^2 < 1
```

I know how to filter with values in 1 array but since I need to use 2, I am not sure what to do. I am not allowed to use loops of any kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do:

```
X_filtered = X[X**2 + Y**2 < 1]
```

`X**2 + Y**2 < 1` returns a boolean array and accessing `X` on this array returns `X` only at the indices equal to `True`.

Comment: i'm a little confused as to why all answers were downvoted but yours considering they're all essentially in the same vein.  Sad... really.

Comment: @MikeMcMahon If you are wondering if I'm the downvoter, the answer is no. For the reason why I guess it's because the OP explicitly mentions that using `for` is forbidden. That said if spurious downvotes make you really sad you should probably stop being on SO... ;)

Comment: Ouch bad attitude. No I think spurious down votes goes against the general foundation of SO. It's certainly poor attitude to recommend people leave if they don't like it when "it" has never been the intention. ;)

Comment: Totally agree with you, maybe the ;) was not making clear enough that I was being sarcastic. It was an (obviously poor) way to say that I too find spurious downvotes are far too common on SO. (Note: that my answer got downvoted too for absolutely no reason...)

Answer (score -1):

```
for ind,(a,b) in enumerate(zip(x,y)) :
     if (a**2 + b**2) < 1 :
        print ind
```

Comment: the requirement for this does not allow the usage of loops of any kinds.

Answer (score -1):

`X = [X[i] for i in range(len(X)) if X[i]**2 + Y[i]**2 < 1]`

this will filter X so that X only contains those that match your filtering criteria.

Note that this does use looping via comprehension, so I am not quite sure how this is to be done without looping.

Answer (score -1):

So I think these arrays are too large to loop? If you only want to **keep** the indices for later, try [Generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators):

```
def X_indices_filterd(X, Y):
    for i in enumerate(X):
        if (X[i] ** 2 + Y[i] ** 2 < 1) yield i
```

Comment: My bad. I have answered without seeing the "numpy" tag. :(